# Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ viewed as a subset of itself an open set? Is it a closed set?

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand open ball concept, and as I saw, if we consider euclidian distance, we can say that, if we consider $\mathbb{R}^n$ subset of itself, an open set. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I believe from your definition. Open sets are union of open balls, but we can write $$\mathbb{R}^N = \cup_{r=1}^{\infty} B_r(0)$$ where $B_r(0)$ is the open ball of $\mathbb{R}^N$ that is centerted at $0$ with radius $r$.

Comment: The answer is yes, open, and yes, closed.

Comment: tks for answers mates, help me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is clearly a union of open balls so it is open itself.

The structure of the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is known as its *topology*. It is always true that the entire topological space is itself an open set (this is one of the axioms of a topology). :)

Likewise, the empty set is a (vacuous) union of open balls, so the empty set is open. (This also is always true in any topological space.)

Closed sets are complements of open sets, so since $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the empty set are open, we also have that the empty set (the complement of $\mathbb{R}^n$) and $\mathbb{R}^n$ (the complement of the empty set) are also closed. :)

Comment: tks @BillCook, your post help me very much.